# Vue.js router-link css prop

Tags: html, css, vue.js

I've been struggling to change the default css props on text written within the router-link tag.
The default is purple with underscore and i would like to change the font, size and color but haven't been able to. Where in my CSS should i focus?
I have tried the "text-decoration: none" within my .sidebar-buttons button css element.

[This is the design as of now i want to change.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JBgxp.png)

```css
.sidebar {
  grid-area: 2 / 1 / 6 / 2;
  background-color: grey;
}
.sidebar-buttons button {
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 12px;
  width: 40%;
  height: 7vh;
}
.sidebar-buttons button:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 10px 10px -10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
  transform: scale(1.1);
}
```

```html
<div class="sidebar">
  <div class="sidebar-buttons">
  <hr />
  <button>
    <router-link to="/">Home</router-link>
  </button>
  <br />
  <button>
    <router-link to="/clothes">Clothes</router-link>
  </button>
  <br />
  <button>
    <router-link to="/skate">Skate</router-link>
  </button>
  <br />
  <hr />
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ding ding ding! Finally made it work.
I had to put the text written in the router-link tag within a a-tag then css prop the a-tag. Hope this helps someone in the future!

```css
.sidebar {
  grid-area: 2 / 1 / 6 / 2;
  background-color: grey;
}
.sidebar-buttons button {
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 12px;
  width: 40%;
  height: 7vh;
}
.sidebar-buttons button:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 10px 10px -10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
  transform: scale(1.1);
}
.sidebar-buttons button a{
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<div class="sidebar">
  <div class="sidebar-buttons">
  <hr />
  <button>
    <router-link to="/"><a>Home</a></router-link>
  </button>
  <br />
  <button>
    <router-link to="/clothes"><a>Clothes</a></router-link>
  </button>
  <br />
  <button>
    <router-link to="/skate"><a>Skate</a></router-link>
  </button>
  <br />
  <hr />
  </div>
</div>
```